# Absolutely positioned element not displaying inside overflow parent

Tags: html, css

I have markup as below:

```
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item visible">
      Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      Item 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In the above markup 'nav' tag is `overflow: auto`. And visible list item's pseudo class(after) is having a  background-color, height.

My question here is: below the visible list item the border-bottom of `nav` shouldn't be visible. It should be overwritten by visible list item's pseudo class after's border-bottom.

Is there any possibility to get this thing done without adding additional elements or removing overflow: auto from `nav`

Comment: JSFiddle URL is: https://jsfiddle.net/MansoorBellary1989/jaxht16f/5/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of using JSFiddle, please edit your question and use an inline [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). This will allow us to see your demonstration without relying on external resources.

Comment: You should add more info to the question and post your CSS here as well. The fact you're using flexbox might be important too - I'm no expert on those.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<nav/>` element with class `.nav` is specified with `overflow: auto`; This will turn it into a scrollable element when your `li.nav-item` has `:after`. Easier way is to remove `overflow:auto` on your `.nav`

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues:

- The nav having an `overflow: auto` means it will have scrollbar if its content is too much. Perhaps you meant to use something else.
- You are mixing `rem` and `px` units in an odd way and expect things to align. The `::after` element is 1.6 pixels tall according to Chrome's inspection tools, which apparently gets trimmed to 1 pixel on my device. The `bottom: -2px;` instruction therefore moves the element completely under the list, below the border you're trying to cover. Using `1px` height and `-1px` bottom position should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't have your element be contained within a clipping parent AND have your element not be clipped. So, you have to bring your element out of its parent -- one way to do that is to make it absolute.

Add the following:

```
.list-item.visible {
  position: absolute;
}
.list-item.visible + .list-item {
  margin-left: 72px;
}
```

And because someone asked for a Stack Snippet, here is the full thing:

```css
.nav {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: wheat;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list-item {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.list-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: .3rem;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
} 

.list-item.visible::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: .1rem;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
}

.list-item.visible {
  position: absolute;
}
.list-item.visible + .list-item {
  margin-left: 72px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item visible">
      Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      Item 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

*Note: You probably though of this, but put the absolute on the ::after; whereas, it has to be on the parent of the ::after; the list-item itself.*